# Remove words between special chars

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

How to remove all words between two special chars using sed? Note that the original line has to be in the result aswell.

Current code:

```
echo 'a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123' | sed -r '/\W/ p; s/\W[^\W]*\W//g'
```

Result:

```
a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123
a123
```

Expected result:

```
a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123
a  b  c d .123
```

Comment: You would need "reluctant" matching that doesn't exist in sed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-reluctant-regex-matching-in-sed) for alternatives.

Comment: `#d+` will be also removed due to the rule *words between special chars* - it won't be in the result

Comment: If *removeme# is removed, the next "pair" of special chars would be + and ~ and everything between and including should be removed.

Comment: What counts as a "special char"? Is it merely non-alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your very special case, you can:

- replace all the unwanted characters by a single known character (whihc is part of that set)
- delete all the strings between two instances of that replacement character

```
echo 'a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123' | sed -e '/\W/p; s/["+*#~]/#/g ; s/#[^#]\+#//g'
a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123
a  b  c d .123
```

Note that since you want to keep the `.`, you cannot use 'non-word' class since these include the '.'. If you want to avoid giving an explicit list of characters at all costs you can:

- replace the dot by a word character that you aren't likely to encounter (thorn, slashed O, accented a/e/i/o/u, or greek/cyrillic)
- apply the expression above using [:punct:]
- reinstate the dot.

Comment: This works for the case above, but if the input is "aaaa#x# bbb.123", the new line in the output is "aaaa bbb@123" so it replaces the dot with @, which generates a new line that I do not want to have. Instead I want to keep the dot from the input. Sorry for being not clear enough, the post has been edited.

Comment: You can replace the `[:punct:]` with an explicit list of characters. Note that in your own code, `\W` would also match a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Change all dots to newlines, guaranteed to not be present AND ensures a non punctuation char as well. Then it's a simple matter of non greedy matching between two punctuation chars:

```
$  echo 'a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123' |
   sed -e 'p
     y/./\n/
     s/[[:punct:]][^[:punct:]]*[[:punct:]]//g
     y/\n/./
   '

a "removeme" b +removeme+ c *removeme#d+removeme~ .123
a  b  c d .123
```

Note: this is all within Posix sed.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is skillful at handling such cases. We use negative lookahead to create a category of punctuation chars excluding  the dot :

```
echo '......' |
perl -lpe '
 print;
 $p = qr/(?!\.)[[:punct:]]/;
 s/$p.*?$p//g;
'
```